# Delegate methods not being called? (CoreBluetooth)

Tags: swift, core-bluetooth

I am using CoreBluetooth in Swift 3 to simulate a serial port with BTLE. The service is visible to central devices, and any updates peripheral (swift) side are updated central side without an issue.

When I send a read or write request from the central side, one of the peripheralManager() delegate methods is supposed to handle the event; however, no matter what happens none of the delegate methods ever get called and the central device eventually loses it's connection (due to timeout, I believe).

```
class BTConnectionHandler: NSObject, CBPeripheralManagerDelegate {

var cbManager: CBPeripheralManager!

var serialService: CBMutableService!
var tx: CBMutableCharacteristic!
var rx: CBMutableCharacteristic!

override init() {

    super.init()

    cbManager = CBPeripheralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    cbManager.startAdvertising(ADVERTISEMENT_DATA)

    serialService = CBMutableService(type: SERIAL_UUID, primary: true)
    tx = CBMutableCharacteristic(type: TX_UUID, properties: TX_PROPERTIES, value: nil, permissions: TX_PERMISSIONS)
    rx = CBMutableCharacteristic(type: RX_UUID, properties: RX_PROPERTIES, value: nil, permissions: RX_PERMISSIONS)
    serialService.characteristics = [tx,rx]

    cbManager.add(serialService)

}

// PERIPHERAL (this) Write to TX
internal func write(string: String) -> Bool {
    let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
    tx.value = data
    return cbManager.updateValue(data,for: tx,onSubscribedCentrals: nil)
}

// PERIPHERAL (this) Read from RX
internal func read() -> String? {
    if let outString = String(data: rx.value!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
        return outString
    } else {
        print("RX buffer is empty")
        return nil
    }
}

// CENTRAL read from TX
func peripheralManager(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, didReceiveRead request: CBATTRequest) {
    print("Read request received from central device")
    request.value = tx.value
    cbManager.respond(to: request, withResult: .success)
}

// CENTRAL write to RX
func peripheralManager(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, didReceiveWrite requests: [CBATTRequest]) {
    print("Write request(s) received from central device")
    for request in requests {
        rx.value = request.value
        cbManager.respond(to: request, withResult: .success)
    }
}

// Print state of peripheral manager as it changes
func peripheralManagerDidUpdateState(_ peripheral:CBPeripheralManager) {

   print(peripheral.state)

}


}
```

Comment: It is odd that this code is working and receiving connections, since you need to wait until you get a powered on state in `peripheralManagerDidUpdateState` before you can advertise any services.

Comment: Also, your receive code looks wrong; you shouldn't store the received data into the `rx` characteristic.  Rather, you should add it to some buffer that your app is going to read (and preferably post a notification or invoke a callback to notify your code that data is available)

Comment: I was planning on using rx as that buffer you're describing, would that not work? Also the peripheralManagerDidUpdateState method never gets called either, I had a switch case in there to start advertising only when powered up but it was never called :P

Comment: and is it possible to notify the peripheral side that a characteristic has been changed? I figured didReceiveWrite would handle that

Comment: You are testing on a real device aren't you?  The problem with your current receive process is that it requires polling to get the received data and there is the possibility of losing data if you don't poll quickly enough.

Comment: Is this your actual code?  The delegate method signatures are wrong.  What version of Xcode and iOS are you targeting?

Comment: Yeah I'm testing this with BLE scanner on an Android device and the swift program above on a Mac... and ohhhh so I can't just write a string to the characteristic value the way the write method works on the Mac side? Because that one works nicely, the central device gets the updated value almost instantly

Comment: and Swift 3 in the new Xcode beta, running on OSX. I'm having a grand old time converting every project over xD... eventually I plan to have this running on a beaglebone running debian but this is a nice testing step

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115467/discussion-between-paulw11-and-joey-hanlon).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem which had me stumped for hours.
My problem was Properties. As soon as I added the .read property, the `didReceiveRead` callback was called:

```
myCharacteristic = CBMutableCharacteristic(
    type: myUUID,
    properties: [CBCharacteristicProperties.notify, CBCharacteristicProperties.read], //*** Need Read Permission to READ!!
    value: nil,
    permissions: CBAttributePermissions.readEncryptionRequired
)
```